# Any .htaccess rule results in a 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an `.htaccess` problem on my `localhost` Apache server. If I put anything in the `.htaccess` file, I get an `Internal Server Error`. I'm trying

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
```

or

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.htm $1.php
```

But they all return the same error.

Comment: There might be a more detailed description of the error in the server logs.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your  [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) setting does not include neither `Options` nor `FileInfo`.